# Raw Json data in request in liferay web service

Tags: json, web, service, liferay, param

I am using **liferay 6.2** & i have invoked few web services.The thing is that when passing parameters as **form data** it works fine, get the json response, but the issue is when pass parameters as **raw data json form** it gives error **"message": "No JSON web service action associated with path /login/user-login and method POST for //xxx-portlet"**

This means it doesn't work with **Content-Type: application/json**. I was trying these things through **postman** the tool in chrome.I want the my json web service should **accept** the **json raw data** in request.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to log in via JSON? There is not such API. You can only call the struts action for that.

Comment: Thats a custom method in my portlet's service which i have exposed to be used by an android app

Comment: That app will be hitting my services by sending parameters into body in raw json form to get data from liferay DB

Comment: If by app you mean a portlet, you should try to use the ```Liferay.Service``` JavaScript Object. Have a look at localhost:8080/api/jsonws how to use it. If the app is something external, consider to create a custom API layer to handle security properly.